# Redirect to other page if there are no parameters in url, otherwise stay at current page

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, parameters, parameter-passing

I need to redirect from my website if there are **no** parameters in the url with **javascript**, **html**. (redirect with html,js)

For example, if a page on my site was [www.tamoghnak.tk](https://www.tamoghnak.tk)/page and if there were parameters on the current page (e.g. [www.tamoghnak.tk](https://www.tamoghnak.tk)/page.html?code=J0eXAiOij ) then the page should stay at the current page . If there are no parameters on the current page then it should redirect to another page. (e.g. [www.tamoghnak.tk](https://www.tamoghnak.tk)/page.html - redirecting to - [www.tamoghnak.tk](https://www.tamoghnak.tk)/rejected)

---

**Answer:** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66376251/14726086 - which is below

```
<script>
const urlContainParams = window.location.search.length === 0;
if (urlContainParams) window.location.href = 'https://www.tamoghnak.tk/rejected';
</script>
```

Thanks to [Eduardo Sousa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11946670/eduardo-sousa)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by doing this

```
const urlContainParams = window.location.search.length === 0;
if (urlContainParams) window.location.href = 'example.org/rejected';
```